# Fetch Avg using Dataframe in Spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I want to find average of the 'rate' column using scala code in Spark.For that I have created Dataframe and view then use Spark SQL for queries. When I run select query using view it gives proper output But when I perform avg and group by using view then it gives no records.

data.txt is a tab separated file.

```
data.txt :
abandon     -2
abandoned   -2
abandons    -2
```

I want to perform twitter sentiment analysis so I stored tweets in dstream and from dstream generate dataframe then join dataframe with AFINN.txt file dataframe But when I perform below code it fetch null records while performing grouping and avg on DF of AFINN.

```
val consumerKey="xxxxxxxxx"
val consumerSecret="xxxxxxxxxx"
val accessToken="xxxxx-xxxxxxx"
val accessTokenSecret="xxxxxxxx"
val args = Array(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", consumerKey)
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", consumerSecret)
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", accessToken)
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", accessTokenSecret)
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("twitterSentiment").setMaster("local[4]").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts","true")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(10))
val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, Array("#India","#Sports"),StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
val englishTweets = tweets.filter(_.getLang() == "en") 
val textMsg = englishTweets.map( status => (status.getId(), status.getText(),status.getText().split(" ")))
val AFINN = sc.textFile("hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/Input/AFINN1.txt").map(x=> x.split("\t")).map(x=>(x(0).toString,x(1).toInt))
val AFINNDF = AFINN.toDF("word","rate") 
AFINNDF.createOrReplaceTempView("temp")
val DF = spark.sql("select * from temp")
DF.show()
```

Output:

```
+----------+----+
|      word|rate|
+----------+----+
|   abandon|  -2|
| abandoned|  -2|
|  abandons|  -2|
+----------+----+
```

```
val DF = spark.sql("select word,avg(rate) as rating from temp group by word")
//DF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [word: string, rating: double]
```

Output:

```
+----+------+
|word|rating|
+----+------+
+----+------+
```

How to find avg using Spark SQL queries in scala?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I have executed the same query, and i have got the avg as output.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFHRD.png)

Comment: Alternatively, you can skip creating temp table and do this.
val df= AFINNDF.groupBy("word").agg(avg("rate"))

Comment: I tried using val df= DF1.groupBy("word").agg(avg("rate")) but no records are fetched.Can you please give the steps which you did for groupby and avg.

Comment: Can you please show your logic what you have been doing. Try assigning different DF while using groupby .

Comment: I want to perform groupby and avg on dataframe as I mentioned in my question.I followed the steps which I wrote in my question and also tried with,  val AFINNDF = AFINN.toDF("word","rate")               val df= AFINNDF.groupBy("word").agg(avg("rate"))          but it didn't work for me still I am getting the null records.

Comment: Yes, you are right. when I run the simple flow which I mentioned earlier in my post I am able to perform grouping and avg on Dataframe. I edited my post which I am actually doing.

Comment: can you please try assigning to Different DF when you are performing group by at then end. Same name "DF" is being used.

Comment: I tried by assigning different name to last DF still no records are fetched.